# Can,t remove kubuntu-desktop completely

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall

I recently installed kubuntu- desktop in my Ubuntu desktop 16.10. But now even after uninstalling an option called "Plasma" still appear on my Display Manager. Is it possible that Kubuntu once installed caanot be removed completely.Please help me with this issue.

Comment: You're right, no additional DE can be easily removed once installed. `kubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package that has no content in itself but installs all the necessary packages for the said desktop. Removing it changes nothing.

Comment: c'mon man... Every problem have a solution... Right! And I was able to remove xfce session and xubuntu with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Switch on your computer.

Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and `press and hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`.

Press `Return` with this option highlighted.

The pc will start in a terminal, run it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kde),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
 apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

*I explain it: Starts in text-only mode. Mount partitions in read-write mode. Update repositories. Install aptitude and deborphan. It eliminates the components of kubuntu that are not necessary in Ubuntu. It eliminates the components of kde that are not necessary in Ubuntu. Reinstall ubuntu-desktop.Eliminates orphan packages. Removes unnecessary packages. Removes downloaded packages. Restart System.*

Comment: Let me try it and I"ll leave a comment if this works or either way